# PHP PDO: chars ÖÄÅ wont show

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, pdo

Whatever im trying to do. If i insert into with öäå or making a while loop, from rows that are from the db, and contains öäå, it appears like Ã¶Ã¤Ã¥.

It must has something to do with the PDO, because it worked just fine with the mysql_*.

Although I had these attributes in mysql_* :

```
# mysql_set_charset("utf8",$link);
# mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

My connection in PDO looks like this:

```
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";charset:UTF-8", DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

How can I solve this? I believe I also need the "set names" somewhere, how?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://www.galengrover.com/web-development/setting-the-connection-charset-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. Please make it as an answer

Comment: Karem, to notify others about comment replies in posts which are not their own, use `@nickname` like @jleedev. See also [how do comment replies work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: @jleedev please make it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` statement is correct, but you have to execute it every time. You can instruct PDO to automatically run the command:

```
$dsn = sprintf( 'mysql:dbname=%s;host=%s', DB_NAME, DB_HOST );
$driver_options = array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8' );
try {
    $dbc = new pdo($dsn, $user, $pw, $driver_options);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

(via [Galen Grover](http://www.galengrover.com/web-development/setting-the-connection-charset-with-php-mysql/))

Comment: sidenote: You need to replace utf-8 to utf8, else it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`Ã¶Ã¤Ã¥` is what you see if you try to display UTF-8 in a view that is set to a non-UTF decoding scheme.  Either you inserted UTF-8 encoded data into a non-UTF8 database or the the database is UTF8 but the terminal you are displaying the results on is not set to UTF8.